# Anyone tested Codeigniter 2.2 on php 5.6?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, php-5.6

just curious to know, has anyone tested CodeIgniter application on PHP 5.6? We are upgrading our server from 5.3.3 to 5.6 currently running CodeIgniter 2.2 . Will that be fine?
if yes, I would really appreciate if you post your feedback what performance change you have encountered

Answer (score 1):

I have a live site using CI 2.1.3 with php 5.6 that has been running smoothly for more than a year (maybe longer). No CI related problems that I can recall.