# Can not get .css files from the root folder on Codeigniter 2.2.6 when changing server php version from 5.5 to 5.6

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-5.6, php-5.5

I use codeigniter 2.2.6 (recently it was 2.2.1. - changed it few minutes ago but problem is unsolved).
The case is: when i change server PHP version from current 5.5 to 5.6 (tried to change to 7.1 first but... :-( ) i can not get root css files.

For example on PHP 5.5 i can get my main.css file by such request: https://my-domain/css/main.css, just like https://my-domain/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css

But when I switch to PHP 5.6 i cant get https://my-domain/css/main.css, it redirects me to https://my-domain/404
and I still can get subfoldered css: https://my-domain/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css - loads normally.
BTW, files from root js folder also loads normally on any PHP version (https://my-domain/js/main.js)

Any suggestions how to fix this?

I have such folder structure:

`-APPROOT/:
--application/
--...
--css/:
---main.css
---bootstrap/:
----bootstrap.min.css
...
--js/:
---main.js
...
--system`

Comment: Very little chance that PHP is the culprit. Are you using the same PHP INI file for both versions?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40051122/anyone-tested-codeigniter-2-2-on-php-5-6, no problems whatsoever reported. Did you copy config/routes.php, etc. and .htaccess ?

Comment: a VERY useful piece of information you ommited: what does your browser's console and network tab say about this?

Comment: I use vagrant to build server, every single byte of the project is the same (includig config files,. htaccess etc) , the only thing i change before "vagrant up" is php version. Console says nothing, resources say that request goes for css, but resposse is html with 404 error

Comment: Does the rendered HTML change? What tools have you used to look for deprecated code? Have you tried running the entry point page on the server to see console errors? Have you checked the web server and php error logs?

Answer (score 0):

use [`base_url()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) function to get the url of the site

`base_url()` gives the url of the website where the index file is located.

eg: `/my-domain/`

or you can give  the file location as the parameter: `base_url('/css/indexpage.css')` then use it as `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('/css/indexpage.css');?>" media="all"/>`